# Chrome iOS webkit speech-recognition

Tags: ios, google-chrome, speech-recognition

I'm trying to implement speech recognition on Chrome on the iPad without any luck. Just to cut to the chase and remove any dependencies on my implementation of the webkitSpeechRecognition api, Glenn Shire's [excellent sample code](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API) does not run on Chrome v27 on an iPad 1 running iOS 5.1.1 or Chrome v31 on an iPad3 running iOS 7.0.4, at least as far as I can tell. It fails at this line:

```
 if (!('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)) {
    r.onState('upgrade');
    return;
 }
```

I can't figure out a workaround, and I've not seen any online postings that say anything about speech recognition not working in the iOS version of Chrome. Anyone else run into this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross Browser Speech Recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789249/cross-browser-speech-recognition)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chrome on iOS doesn't support Speech Recognition at the moment.

Google have to use iOS UIWebView that mean there is no special web interpretation feature that are not supported on Safari.

You may have a look to [this link](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/faq).

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to recognize few simple commands you can look on [Pocketsphinx.js](http://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js)

The code to recognize speech is simple:

```
var id = 0;
recognizer.postMessage({command: 'initialize', callbackId: id});
var keyphrase = "HELLO WORLD";
recognizer.postMessage({command: 'addKeyword', data: keyphrase, callbackId: id});
recognizer.postMessage({command: 'start', data: id});
recognizer.postMessage({command: 'process', data: array});
recognizer.postMessage({command: 'stop'});

recognizer.onmessage = function(e) {
     if (e.data.hasOwnProperty('hyp')) {
           alert(e.data.hyp);
     }
};
```

For more details see also the full example [here](https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js/blob/master/webapp/live.html)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.