# Cross Browser Speech Recognition

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-browser, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am currently working on a project in ASP.NET. I need to add voice command which will work on IE/Chrome/Firefox. I have searched a lot, but haven't found any solutions for cross browser.

Is there any JavaScript framework to do it?
Can i use Google web speech API as a service?

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Well i ended up creating a desktop service which uses Microsoft speech API to take input and convert to text and then communicate with the browser with web sockets.

Answer (score 5):

You can check support for speech recognition in various browsers at [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-recognition). At the moment only Chrome supports speech recognition reliably. Others don't, including IE, Firefox and Safari. Firefox is working on the speech recognition support, but it's not there yet.

If your browser supports [getUserMedia](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream) to record audio you can record the audio and send it to the server for recognition. You can also use javascript-only recognizer [Pocketsphinx.js](https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js) if you want to recognize few simple commands.

On browsers which do not support getUserMedia API you can use Flash object or java applet to capture audio. That's pretty much your only option if you prioritize IE.

Comment: I have already considered Pocketsphinx.js. But my client gives higher priority in IE.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done as long as the browser supports HTML5's getUserMedia API:

1. Use HTML5's getUserMedia to capture an audio stream
2. Save it to .WAV, there are libraries for that
3. Send the .WAV to the server through AJAX
4. Feed the .WAV to SpeechRecognitionEngine, through the SetInputToWaveFile method
5. Get the result and return it in the AJAX call

An example:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/speech-recognition-in-asp-net