# Speech recognition API for all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have seen Google Speech API which is only working on chrome 25+ versions and HTML5 Speech API
 is also working on chrome only. I am wondering is there any good Javascript/ Jquery API so that i can used it to work on my project. Please if anyone can help me out that would be great. I am searching alot but all the examples are using google speech API. i would prefer Javascript API but if i can even get C# or PHP API and worked on all browsers that should be fine as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why this is off topic ?

Comment: Because you asked for library recommendations. The relevant rule is quoted above.

Comment: well there is a difference between software library and API. I have defined my problem and have come up with google API which is chrome dependent and other Jquery examples are using the same API. I am not asking for any solutions or something like that i am asking for the expert opinion and then going to implement it.i have search alot and did not find anything.I simply asked for the API may be anyone has implemented anything. If you dont like this question then you can go there http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=speech%20recognition%20api and put this offtopic toall questions Thanks

Comment: 1) "asking for expert opinion" - opinion questions are why library recommendations are off-topic in the first place. 2) It is not Chrome API, it is HTML5 API that Webkit browsers happen to implement. 3) jQuery cannot do anything that JavaScript cannot do, so asking for a jQuery API makes no sense. 4) The snippet above clearly states what you need to do to to have any chance of being put off hold. Being belligerent is not one of those things. 5) I actually answered both your initial question as well as the follow-up. Thank you for your rudeness in return.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789249/cross-browser-speech-recognition

Comment: absolutely valid and useful question, no reason to close it. Who runs this place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speech API only currently works on Chrome and Opera ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-speech)). You cannot use C# or PHP API in a browser, since those are serverside technologies. What you could do is record audio on clientside, post it to the server, and have the server recognise it; I believe C# can use `System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognizer`, and there are several solutions you can use from PHP.

Comment: Chrome and Opera, not Safari

Comment: and what's FF/IE ways to record the audio