# Speech Recognition In Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, speech-recognition

I see HTML5 has nice set of JS classes which helps us integrate voice capability to the website (speak to type and speak to command) very easily. However it looks like it mainly for Chrome and managed by Google.

I can't find how to get it working with similar technology for Internet Explorer.

Do anybody have any reference or example link which I can refer?

Comment: Please specify the IE versions that you need to support. Also, do you want to support Edge as well, or just IE?

Comment: We will be using latest version of IE

Comment: So that's IE11? Or do you mean Edge? (given that the feature you want is in development in Edge, that might be a better option)

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915109/speech-recognition-api-for-all-browsers

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition#Browser_compatibility they do not support webkitSpeechRecognition.

[image]

That is for built in browser support. Now if you would like to pay for this support you could use IBM Bluemix or Google Speech api.

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text.html  OR
https://cloud.google.com/

Comment: Thanks Alex, I know webkitSpeechRecognition is not supported by IE. I know I could use Google Speech API but I really need an example how that can be done using JavaScript. Would it be compulsory for me to use either Silverlight or Flash to record audio in IE? I want it to be done in plain HTML file.

Comment: Google has a few node.js and Python examples. If you aren't going to have a server, you could also give pocketsphinx a try. You could included it using the js html tag.

Comment: Also don't use flash, it is insecure and will not be supported going forward.

Comment: Alex, any idea how SpeechRecognition which is supported on chromium browser works? I mean how it converts audio into text? Any background around would helpful to me

Comment: It has been around for a few years (and works pretty well - I have used it in the past). This is a solid overview: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API . Make sure to follow some of the links, they will take you to the w3 specifications. Another great resource is MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

Answer (score 0):

The speech recognition APIs that you're referring to are indeed new and not fully supported.

They are also ***not*** official HTML5 APIs -- they are currently marked as unofficial. That doesn't mean they won't eventually become official APIs, but for now they are just something that Google thought would be a good idea.

You can find info about them on the [CanIUse website](http://caniuse.com/#search=speech). As you'll see on this page, they are supported in Chrome and Opera, and also in Firefox, although only as an experimental feature, meaning that the user would have to enable the feature manually in the browser.

More significantly in relation to your question, the page also states that they are "In development" for Microsoft Edge. This means that there is a good chance that they'll be available in Edge in a future release, within a reasonable space of time. They are not available now, and will never be available in IE, as Microsoft are only developing new features for Edge now.

Therefore, if you need to support IE, you will need something else. There is nothing standard or even well-known that I can recommend though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have this feature in Internet explorer right now. May be in the future they would implement this functionality.Let me give you an example- the link below is by microsoft teams describing the text-to-speech functionality by a demo application. Try running it on Internet Explorer, it won't work. So whoever asks you to achieve this, show this example.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/testdrive/demos/speechsynthesis/

They have separated out the code for browsers which doesn't support the speechsynthesis object. Do have a look in the developer tools for better understanding.