# SpeechRecognition is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

I am trying to test *webspeech-api* of firefox but encountering an error in the console saying **ReferenceError: SpeechRecognition is not defined**.

I have even enabled `media.webspeech.recognition.enable` and `media.webspeech.synth.enabled` flags in about:config.

Is there a way to make **SpeechRecognition** work on firefox?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915109/speech-recognition-api-for-all-browsers?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [this blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/01/firefox-and-the-web-speech-api/) from January 21, 2016 by Chris Mills (a senior tech writer at Mozilla) **you can't use it yet in web environment on FF ...**

> ... because the UX/UI to allow users to grant an app permission to use it is not yet implemented.

...

Here is a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1248897) for which you can vote.

And currently, you'll have to be in the `chrome` environment (extension) to use it.

---

#### Update winter 2019

The linked bug report has been marked as fixed.

To enable the SpeechRecognition in **Firefox Nightly > 72**, go to `about:config` and switch the flags `media.webspeech.recognition.enable` and `media.webspeech.recognition.force_enable` to true.

However note this is an online service, which means you'll need an internet connection.

Comment: It's 2024 and this still doesnt work in Firefox... how weird