# SpeechRecognization for firefox web extension

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, speech-recognition, firefox-addon-webextensions

As chrome has **webkitspeechrecognition** api for speech detection , what can we use for firefox webextension(web speech api not working for me).

I'm making an extension which will continuously listen for speech and then process it.
I have already made a chrome extension which is up and running,so wanted to extend it to Firefox, need an alternative to this line(which is for chrome extension)

```
recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpeechRecognition is not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784986/speechrecognition-is-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev as mentioned by firefox they will release the api for firefox in Q2 of 2018 and that question dates back to 2016 so its not updated one !Any ways i got my answer, API is not yet released and will be released soon!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Speech Recognition API yet, but you should be able to use

```
recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
```

In order for this to work, you need to set

```
media.webspeech.recognition.enable
```

to true in about:config. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API

There are a number of outstanding bugs around the implementation of Web Speech in Firefox, so I'm not sure the above is implemented or working well. The basic implementation was done in Firefox 44 / 49.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did tried this doesn't work.

Comment: Which Firefox version did you use? What is the error in the browser console?

Comment: OK cool ill try on them ! I needed generalized speech API.Anyways thanks a lot ill try that