# Vue.js webkitSpeechRecognition integration

Tags: javascript, webkit, speech-recognition, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to connect webkitSpeechRecognition to my Vue.js project (for Chrome).

I'm trying to insert code into component

```
<template>
      <div class="voice">
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
        <button v-on:click="greet">Speak</button>
      </template>

      <script>
      export default {
        name: 'voice',
        data () {
          return {
            msg: 'Speak',
          }
        },
        methods: {
          greet: function (event) {

          }
        }
      }
      </script>
```

this code

```
var recognition = new (SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition || mozSpeechRecognition || msSpeechRecognition)();
recognition.lang = 'en-US';
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 5;
recognition.start();

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    console.log('You said: ', event.results[0][0].transcript);
};
```

but i have error "webkitSpeechRecognition is not defined"

Comment: It depends on the browser presumably, only supported in Chrome, not in any webkit-based browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speech recognition API for all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915109/speech-recognition-api-for-all-browsers)

Answer (score 5):

I solved it with this line:

```
var recognition = new window.webkitSpeechRecognition
```