# How to enable Webkit speech to text in chromium 51?

Tags: chromium, raspberry-pi2, speech-to-text

I am using Jessie on raspberry pi, the default browser support is chromium V51, but i am unable to run webkit speech to text module, which is running very fine in Google Chrome. Please help me if anyone has solved this previously.

I am open for other opinion regarding speech to text using nodejs.

thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross Browser Speech Recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789249/cross-browser-speech-recognition)

Comment: It is not supported.