# Are there any limitations with using Chrome Speech Recognition?

Tags: google-chrome, speech-recognition

I want to use webkit-speech-recognition in my commercial web-application.

Are there any limitations (limit of queries by site, prohibition of commercial use)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a timeout after 5 minutes (300 seconds)

Though I couldn't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the question. I am curious about this too. Just be weary if you are developing for mobile as HTML5 speech regonition API for Chrome does not work on mobile iOS for iPhone and iPad. See: [Add iOS speech recognition support for web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592170/add-ios-speech-recognition-support-for-web-app)